# How is presupposition of the order of reaction justified in Michaelis-Menten model?

Tags: biochemistry

from what I have understood, to derive Michaelis-Menten equation, we first suppose that

$\ce{E + S <=>[k_1][k_{-1}] ES->[k_2]E + P }$

and make the 'steady-state assumption', that $k_1[E][S]=(k_{-1}+k_2)[ES]$.

But from what I've learned, the order of reaction cannot be derived from its equation, but can only be decided by experiment. How can we 'presuppose' the order of these, especially when both $E$ and $S$ are macromolecules? The left side might as well be $k_1[E][S]^2$, for example.

What am I missing out?

Comment: These are elementary steps.

Comment: This is a basic model for the most simple scenario. There are many much more complicated enzyme kinetic models for reactions in which there are multiple substrates or inhibitors binding in random order or specific order, etc.

Comment: What you suggest about stoichiometry and what the reaction steps actually are is true in general, but in this particular case this model has been confirmed by experiment and that is the only reason it is still used.

Comment: Oh, so it was just because of the simplicity of the model. Thank you all!